# Utilizing a UIActivityIndicatorView and CorePlot-CocoaTouch causes memory prblem

Tags: ios5, core-plot, uiactivityindicatorview

Utilising CorePlot-Cocoa Touch in an IOS5.1 app. Since the setting up of the scatterplots, dataForPlots, legends etc takes time, decided to include a UIActivityIndicatorView to indicate something is happening to the user.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

   [super viewWillAppear:animated];

   progressInd = [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleGray];
   progressInd.center = self.view.center;
   [progressInd sizeToFit];
   progressInd.hidden = NO;
   progressInd.alpha = 1.0;

  [self.view addSubview:progressInd];
  [progressInd startAnimating];
  [self.view bringSubviewToFront:progressInd];

  [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(DoMakeupPlot) withObject:nil];   

}

- (void)DoMakeupPlot
{
    … set up plot
    … including datasource and delegate

   [progressInd stopAnimating];
   [progressInd removeFromSuperview];
   progressInd = nil;
}
```

Now this seems to work on occasion, however it's apparent that there becomes 2 Threads calling the plot datasource routines:

> -(NSUInteger)numberOfRecordsForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot
>
> -(NSNumber *)numberForPlot:(CPTPlot *)plot field:(NSUInteger)fieldEnum recordIndex:(NSUInteger)index

which does on occasion cause memory problems and the app crashes.

Experimented  exiting these 2 Threads from within the 2 above routines, but this causes other problems.

Now prior to using this UIActivityIndicatorView, whereby the 2 routines above are called from the MainThread, all is good.

Also tried this with the MBProgressHud, and obviously have the same problem.

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    
    HUD = [[MBProgressHUD alloc] initWithView:self.view];
    [self.view addSubview:HUD];
    
    HUD.delegate = self;
    HUD.labelText = @"Loading";
    HUD.detailsLabelText = @"plot data";
    HUD.square = YES;
    
    [HUD showWhileExecuting:@selector(DoMakeupPlot) onTarget:self withObject:nil animated:YES];
}
```

How do I remove the Thread which performs the number crunching, whilst the MainThread does the UIActivityIndicatorView, after it has done the setting up?

Help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Don't set the datasource until `-DoMakeupPlot` finishes. That way the plot doesn't try to load data from the datasource that's not ready yet.

Comment: Thanks, that was going to be the next step, setting up datasource & delegate after Activity Indicator finished.